# How to use INT() function inside an IF() statement Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have almost eight thousand columns containing floating point numbers. But some of these contain numbers like `223,0` which returns a `TRUE` with the `INT()` function. So, I decided to use the `IF` statement to perform a calculation only on the rows with integers but the formula `=IF(INT(F3)=TRUE,1,2)` returns an error. So, how do you properly use `INT()` inside `IF()`?

Comment: You may use this `=IF(INT(A1)=A1,1,2)` or even this `=IF(A1>INT(A1),"IS Not","IS Int")` will work .

Comment: @RajeshS Both of them return an error for some reason. Excel just doesn't recognize them as a formula.

Comment: ,,, reason is `Decimal symbol` ,, `223,0` should be `223.0` ,, check the settings!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few options really that I can think of right now to check for a whole number:

```
=IF(INT(F3)=F3,1,2)
```

Or:

```
=IF(MOD(F3,1)=0,1,2)
```

Or:

```
=IF(F3-TRUNC(F3)=0,1,2)
```

Or:

```
=IF(MROUND(F3,1)=F3,1,2)
```

---

Looking at the comment section it seems you are working with the "," as a decimal point. So you probably want the parameters of the formula seperated with a semicolon `;` isntead of a comma `,`.

Comment: Your 1st Formula is as similar as mine ,, please change or remove it ☺

Comment: Both of them return an error for me. "There's a problem with this formula."

Comment: @Coder_fox,, no all formula are working properly 2 suggested by me through comments & 2 by #JvdV!

Comment: @RajeshS I understand that but what could cause such behavior of rejecting known good formulas?

Comment: @Coder_fox,, check settings problem is `,`  should `.` or set `,` as decimal!!

Comment: @RajeshS - If the OP is using `,` as a decimal point, might they also be using `;` instead of `,` as the system list separator? Maybe the formulas should be written with `;` instead of commas.

Comment: @Jeeped,, yeah it may be also that's Y I've suggested OP to check Settings.

Comment: @RajeshS, you can post your comment as answer and I'll upvote since it's the shortest solution and I see you posted that before I did. But I don't see why I should remove it from mine.

Comment: @JvdV,, it's okay I was just suppose to prompt you and nothing else,,, ☺

Comment: So, the issue was that the format rewires a ```;``` between the parameters.